# Scrapy can't return item when using yield?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'll try to abstract my code because it's a bit big.

So this function is used to parse a forum thread

```
def parse_thread_next_pages(self,response):
    print("----- Scraping new NEXT THREAD PAGE ------")
    for r in replies_body:
        #Here I'm doing some parsing and adding to 'myitem'

        if absolute_next_page_url=="javascript:;":
        #We reached the last page, myitem contains all the information I need, I want to break and return it
            break
        else:
            #This yield is used to call this function recursively for each pages
            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_next_page_url, callback=self.parse_thread_next_pages,meta={'myitem': myitem})
    return myitem
```

The problem is, when I do `scrapy crawl spider -t json -o result.json`, it is empty. However, if I comment out the `yield` line it works. But then obviously I don't get the result expected because this parse function is not called recursively.

Why does this happen and how can I return my item after having called this function recursively and reached the last page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing how [python generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) work.

One alternative to your problem would be to change the final `return` to also a `yield`. That shouldn't conflict with your functionality, Scrapy handles two things from their callbacks, requests and items.